# Should normalisation factor in a QM always be positive?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, normalization

I have a fairly simple question about a normalisation factor. After normalising a wavefunction for a particle in an infinite square well on an interval $-L/2<x<L/2$ I got a quadratic equation for a normalisation factor $A_0$ which has a solution like this:

$$A_0 = - \frac{8\pi}{6} \pm \sqrt{\frac{8^2\pi^2}{36}+\frac{3}{4}}$$

The sign $\pm$ gives me two options while a normalisation factor can only be one value. So I want to know if there are any criteria on which i could decide which value to choose. Is it possible that normalisation factor should always be a positive value?

---

I added the procedure I used to derive this eq. :

[image]

Comment: I havent found a statement like this in my book though.

Comment: The thing to be normalized is positive definite, right? And it is to be made equal to 1 not -1, right? So ...

Comment: The wave function is only defined up to a phase so the sign of the normalization can't matter. But I'm confused how you got to such a point... You should always get an eqn of the form $|a|^2 \times \int \psi^* \psi=1$, you should never end up with a solution for a like you are describing with two branches with different absolute values.

Comment: Well my wave function is something like $\psi(x) = A_0\sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{L}x\right) + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{L}x\right)$. It describes an electron in an infinite potential well on an interval $-L/2>x>L/2$... Thats what I got after normalisation. I will doublecheck again.

Comment: @71GA: Are you sure your wavefunction is correct? I don't see any dependency on $n_x$... And the interval must be $-L/2 < x < L/2$, I think.

Comment: @71GA you made errors early on. Firstly, the functions are **not orthogonal** on the interval $[-L/2,L/2]$, they are in fact the eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian for an infinite potential well with walls at $x=0,L$. Secondly, you assumed $A_0$ was real in your calculation. Thirdly, a $\pi$ magically jumped from the denominator to the numerator. There could be more errors, but that's what jumps out at me.

Comment: It would be much better if you transcribe the important bits of your work using MathJax, and then just link to the image rather than including it inline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I think you made a mistake.**

---

Using your wavefunction and noting that $$\int^\frac{L}{2}_{-\frac{L}{2}}
\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{L}\right)\sin\left(\frac{2\pi x}{L}\right) = \frac{4L}{3\pi}$$ we see that
$$1=\int^{L/2}_{-L/2}|\psi(x)|^2 dx = \frac{2}{L}\left(|A_0|^2\frac{L}{2} +\frac{4L}{3\pi}
\left(A_0 + A_0^*\right)+ \frac{1}{4}\frac{L}{2}\right) = \left(|A_0|^2 +\frac{8}{3\pi}
\left(A_0 + A_0^*\right)+ \frac{1}{4}\right)$$
and so we have the **constraint**
$$\boxed{|A_0|^2 +\frac{8}{3\pi}
\left(A_0 + A_0^*\right)+ \frac{1}{4} = 1}$$
If we let $A_0 = a+ib$, with $a,b$ real, this reduces to
$$a^2+b^2 +\frac{16}{3\pi}a
+ \frac{1}{4} = 1
$$
If we make the choice that **$A_0$ is real**, that is $A_0 = a$ we find
$$A_0^2 +\frac{16}{3\pi} A_0
+ \frac{1}{4} = 1 ~~\implies ~~ \boxed{A_0 = -\frac{8}{3\pi}\pm\sqrt{\left(\frac{8}{3\pi}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}}}$$
which is what I am guessing you were trying to get. We see that the most general solution involves both $a$ and $b$ - it is complex. To find a **general result**, parameterized by $a$ we solve 
$$a^2+b^2 +\frac{16}{3\pi}a
+ \frac{1}{4} = 1~~\implies ~~ b = \pm \sqrt{\frac{3}{4}-a^2-\frac{16}{3\pi}a}$$
and so our general solution is
$$\boxed{A_0 = a \pm i\sqrt{\frac{3}{4}-a^2-\frac{16}{3\pi}a}}
$$
(note we must restrict $a$ to take values for which $\sqrt{\frac{3}{4}-a^2-\frac{16}{3\pi}a}$ is real). So we have a range of possible solutions. *I cannot see any way to make a choice of one solution over any other.*

---

**Added after comments below:**

It is likely that the question (wherever you found it) has a typo and the interval of interest is actually $[0,L]$. This makes more sense, because the first two **energy eigenstates** of an infinite square well potential on the interval $[0,L]$ are (up to a normalization) $\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{L}\right)$ and $\sin\left(\frac{2\pi x}{L}\right)$. Under this scenario, the problem of normalization is much simpler, because these two functions are **orthogonal** *on this interval*. This means that we have
$$1 = \int^L_0 dx |\psi(x)|^2 = |A_0|^2 + \frac{1}{4} \implies |A_0| = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
so we would have $A_0 = e^{i\theta}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ for arbitrary, real $\theta$.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I will look into your anwser. I saw your shorter anwser before you deleted it and the result $A_0 = \sqrt{3}/2$ is the one i should get by the book. Could you include the explaination from before aswell in an EXTENDED anwser or so.

Comment: Are you certain that the region of interest is $[-L/2,L/2]$? If it was $[0,L]$ then the two sine functions are orthogonal and you find the simple result $A_0 = e^{i\theta}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. It seems more likely that this is what the author meant - then the wavefunction has been expanded in an orthogonal basis.

Comment: It is written that the interval is $-L/2 < x < L/2$. I am sure. But author states that the result is $A_0 = \sqrt{3}/2$. Arent two states for example for quantum number $N=1$ and $N=2$ **always** orthogonal? Oh and i included my derivation on the paper. Latex would simply be too long.

Comment: Are you dealing this a square well potential? If so, dealing with the interval $[-L/2,L/2]$ means that your $N=1$ wavefunction is (up to normalization) $\cos(\pi x/L)$. Think about it. BUT if you are dealing with $[0,L]$ then the orthogonal wavefunctions are the ones above, and you result with $|A_0| = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, as I said.

Comment: *"dealing with the interval [−L/2,L/2] means that your $N=1$ wavefunction is (up to normalization) $cos(πx/L)$"*. **How do we know this?** I did derive wavefunctions for an infinite sq. well on an interval $-L/2<x<L/2$ once and got 2 possible wavefunctions. One for odd and one for even wavevunctions. They were like $\psi = \sqrt{\frac{2}{d}}\sin \left(\frac{(2N-1)\pi}{d}x\right)$ and $\psi = \sqrt{\frac{2}{d}}\cos\left(\frac{N\pi}{d}x\right)$. Each gave only half the spectra. Here is the [original post](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?p=4462683#post4462683).

Comment: The easiest way to see what the eigenfunctions are is to draw some diagrams, noting that we need **zeros** at $-L/2$ and $L/2$. So it is easy to see that the first eigenstate is a cosine function... Try it.

Comment: So my derivation from which i got $\psi = \sqrt{\frac{2}{d}}\sin \left(\frac{(2N-1)\pi}{d}x\right)$ and  $\psi = \sqrt{\frac{2}{d}}\cos\left(\frac{N\pi}{d}x\right)$ was wrong and i have to do it all over again. Our professor said that the interval is $-L/2<x<L/2$ and that normalisation factor is $A_0=\sqrt{3}/2$ which means he made a mistake. I am now totaly lost...

Comment: **Thanks for adding an extended anwser.** My two equations for an infinite potential well that i wrote above for the interval $-d/2<x<d/2$ ($d\equiv L$)are clearly wrong too (if i solve them for $x=\pm d/2$ i don't get zero). Could you participate in [my other topic to where i derived them](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/73083/is-it-possible-that-selection-of-an-interval-affects-the-energy-levels-of-a-part) to help me clear this mess in my head now..

Comment: The two solutions are $\psi(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)$ and $\psi(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\cos\left(\frac{(n-1/2)\pi x}{L}\right)$ for $n$, any integer greater than zero.

Comment: I recalculated them and got a bit different than yours are. I got $\psi(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\sin\left(\frac{2n\pi x}{L}\right)$ and $\psi(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\cos\left(\frac{(2n-1)\pi x}{L}\right)$. Oh bummer...

Comment: @71GA sorry that's a typo on my part. Great! You've worked it out .

Answer (score 2):

Simple: $A_0$ is not a common factor to the *entire* wavefunction. So it's not a normalization factor.

In other words, you have

$$\psi(x) = A_0\sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\sin\biggl(\frac{\pi}{L}x\biggr) + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\sin\biggl(\frac{2\pi}{L}x\biggr)$$

but if you really want $A_0$ to be a normalizing factor you should have

$$\psi(x) = A_0\Biggl[\sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\sin\biggl(\frac{\pi}{L}x\biggr) + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\sin\biggl(\frac{2\pi}{L}x\biggr)\Biggr]$$

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I voted up your anwser.